# Change python version default on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, upgrade, python

I'm using python 3.6.8 as default.  I'm trying to replace it with python 3.7 for my work. How can I do it, I have tried a few ways but they didn't work. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to AskUbuntu!  There are plenty of questions both here and on the web about choosing between python versions.  Can you please edit your question to include what methods you have tried and what version of Ubuntu you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to replace the default installation with a newer version.

Maybe some system tools depend on Python 3.6, and do not work on Python 3.7.

I suggest to install Python 3.7 and just use it directly via `python3.7`.

Answer (score 0):

*i will suggest few steps to update alternatives , first remove all alternatives config*

`sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python`

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 1`

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 2`

*then you can choose any time which version you want to use*

`sudo update-alternatives --config python`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try